# Can you explain Matlab's Text Description of Decision Tree Please?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have trained a decision tree in Matlab using the fitctree command on categorical predictors.

I then use the "view" command like `view(tree)` to get a textual description of the tree. The result doesn't make sense to me because there are only two possible categories yet I get something strange.

The result looks like this:

```
    Decision tree for classification
    if var1=no then node 2 elseif var1=yes then node 3 else class2
```

The problem is var1 can only be yes and no. Why would I be getting that extra `else class2` at the end??? Surely, it should be `if var1=no then node 2 else node 3` at least that's what I expected. Somebody else asked [this here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/203083-how-to-understand-decision-tree-for-classification-text-description), but there was no reasonable answer.

Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `if` statement become `Boolean`, write it like this:

```
 if var1     % means if var1 = yes
 node 3;
 elseif      % if var1 = no
 node 2
 end
```

there is no other `else` because you have only 2 chances "yes or no".